# What are the differences bettween linux system call mmap(2) and posix mmap(3) function?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, posix, embedded-linux, difference

What are the differences bettween linux system call mmap(2) and posix mmap(3) function?
How to distinguish which one is used when broswing the source code,since they have the same header file.For details, see below.

I am running on Ubuntu.I do not think it matters what operating system you are using.The mannual page really does not supply much useful information indeed.

As per the reply of Jörg W Mittag, I think the mmap must be posix function when i am broswing the source code.But i wonder that why i need not to explicitly link to posix library when using the mmamp(3) function .I mean no extra link flag is needed when complie the source code.

As per the reply of Faschingbauer,some question arise if we make the conclusion that no posix mmap is implenmented.You see, there are some posix function implemented（eg, shm_opn、sem_open, mq_open）.In the mean time，there are corresponding ones with the same functions(eg, shmget,semget, msgget).How to explain it?At least, I think some posix functions are implemented by linux.

```
#log for "man 2 mmap"
MMAP(2)  Linux Programmer's Manual                                                         
NAME
       mmap, munmap - map or unmap files or devices into memory
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/mman.h>



#log for "man 3 mmap"
MMAP(3POSIX)  POSIX Programmer's Manual                                                    
PROLOG
       This  manual page is part of the POSIX Programmer's Manual.  The Linux implementation of this interface may differ (consult the corresponding Linux manual page for details of Linux behavior), or the interface may not be implemented on Linux.    
NAME
       mmap — map pages of memory
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/mman.h>
```

Comment: Why do you think those are different functions?

Comment: If you're running on Linux, the Linux mmap is being used. If you're running on NetBSD, the NetBSD mmap is being used, and so on. Refer to the relevant OS's man page to see how it differs from the posix spec.

Comment: Aforementioned posix spec: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/mmap.html

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica  I am running on Ubuntu.I do not think it matters what operating system you are using.

Comment: @Shawn The mannual page really does not supply much useful information indeed.

Answer (score 6):

## POSIX vs. Linux

First, some facts:

1. POSIX is a standard, made by a standards body. *POSIX does not
   implement anything*, but rather define feature set and behavior of
   interfaces. Part of this definition is a number of man pages - the
   "POSIX Programmer's Manual"
2. Linux *implements* the POSIX standard, just like other UNIX
   operating systems do. (I do not know if Linux is "POSIX certified",
   nor do I care.) In implementing the POSIX standard, Linux takes the
   freedom to extend the standard with Linux specific features; hence
   it brings its own set of manual pages, the "Linux Programmer's
   Manual".

Looking at the Linux ("`man 2 mmap`") man page, you can see that it
defines, for example, the `MAP_LOCKED` bit in the flags argument
(btw. `MAP_LOCKED` makes a separate call to `mlock()` unnecessary). This
flag does not appear in the POSIX man page ("`man 3 mmap`"), because it
is not required by the POSIX standard for a conforming implementation.

That said, there is no way to use an alternative implementation of
`mmap()` in Linux. If some source code that you are reading uses `mmap()`,
and you are on Linux, then the Linux implementation of `mmap()` is used, simply
because there is no POSIX implementation of it.

Respectively, the POSIX version is *contained* in the Linux
implementation. Linux is "compatible" with POSIX, so to say - it does
not redefine any feature required by POSIX (this would mean to violate the standard), but only adds extensions
like the `MAP_LOCKED` above.

## Manual Pages

Hm. My personal opinion is that the POSIX version of, say, the `mmap`
man page is only there to confuse users. If you inadvertently hit the
section "3" `mmap()` man page, and you don't know what the relationship
is between POSIX and Linux, then you are indeed seriously confused at
best, or on the wrong track at worst.

I suggest you omit the section number and just say "`man mmap`" - this searches all the manual
sections for occurences of "mmap" and stops at the first (see "`man man`" for the exact definition).

(This does not work as envisioned with "`man write`" when you are
searching for the definition of the `write()` system call, because there
is a command "`write`" with the same same in section "1" :-) )

## System Calls

As stated by "`man man`", manual section "2" contains system call
documentation. Knowing that `mmap()` is implemented by the Linux kernel
(because it is the kernel who implements core OS functionality like
memory management) can only help to clear up the confusion as to
whether the documentation you are reading is what you want.

Comment: @Faschingbauer Thanks your replay.You mean only mmap(2) is implemented by linux os.Posix mmap(3) is not implemented by linux?Am i right?

Comment: That's what I say. There *is no* POSIX mmap implementation, not in Linux, nor anywhere else.

Comment: @Faschingbauer I see.But, there is some question if we make the conclusion that no posix mmap is implenmented.You see, there are some posix function implemented（eg, shm_opn、sem_open, mq_open）.In the mean time，there are corresponding ones with the same functions(eg, shmget,semget, msgget).How to explain it?At least, I think some posix functions are implemented by linux.

Comment: POSIX mmap is implemented in Linux, and is documented by both the "man 3 mmap" (POSIX) manual page and the "man 2 mmap" (Linux) manual page. The latter is a **superset** of the former.

Comment: Then there's **System V IPC** and **POSIX IPC**, which is a related but different story.shm_open(), sem_open(), mq_open() etc are part of POSIX IPC. shmget(), semget(), msgget() etc are part of System V IPC. System V IPC is older and a bit ... well ... crappy I'd say. POSIX IPC is newer and more well defined. For new code, I suggest you use POSIX IPC.

Comment: @ Faschingbauer You said the latter refer to mmap(2) is a superset of the of the mmap(3).I wonder that **which one is used** if I broswing some open source code **besides**  the source code of the runtime library for a C compiler (e.g. GCC's) or the source code of a POSIX library (such as Glibc, dietlibc, µClibc, or musl).

Answer (score 0):

> What are the differences bettween linux system mmap(2) and posix mmap(3) function?

Section 2 documents syscalls. Section 3 documents functions. Therefore, `mmap(2)` is not a function at all, it is a syscall.

> How to distinguish which one is used when broswing the source code?

If it is a function call, it is `mmap(3)`. If it is a syscall, it is `mmap(2)`. Since it is impossible to portably call syscalls from C, there will always be some sort of macro or wrapper function for the syscall.

Also, unless you are reading the source code of the runtime library for a C compiler (e.g. GCC's) or the source code of a POSIX library (such as Glibc, dietlibc, µClibc, or musl), it is highly unlikely that you will find any syscalls in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It puzzled me for a long time.

Comment: I understand your reply.I think the mmap must be posix function when i am broswing the source code.But i wonder that why i need not to explicitly link to posix library when using the mmamp(3) function .I mean no extra link flag is needed when complie the source code.

Answer (score 0):

> But i wonder that why i need not to explicitly link to posix library when using the mmamp(3) function .

You need not link another library because [`mmap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html) is contained in GLIBC; you can see this e. g. with

```
 nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep mmap
00000000000e4610 W mmap
00000000000e4610 W mmap64
```

Comment: I see, thank you for your help.Which one do you think is implemented by linux?Mmap(2) or mmap(3)?

Comment: The library function mmap(3) is implemented in GLIBC and uses the system call mmap(2) which is implemented in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i could draw the conclusion that the mmap must be the posix one when i am browsing the source code of some open projects.Am i right? Could you teach me the way to identify the mmap implemented in C library is the posix one? Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: What's so hard about https://stackoverflow.com/a/61421970/13403020 ?

Comment: @孙世龙: From [Introduction (The GNU C Library)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Introduction.html): _The GNU C Library, described in this document, defines all of the library functions that are specified by the ISO C standard, as well as additional features specific to POSIX and other derivatives of the Unix operating system, and extensions specific to GNU systems._